# Heeadless reboot of Ubuntu 20.04on Raspberry PI

Tags: 20.04, hdmi, raspberrypi, headless

I have successfully set up Ubuntu 20.04 on a raspberry PI 4. It is connected to a TV via HDMI. When I have the TV on and tuned to the PI input the PI boots perfectly. However when  the TV is off or I am using another source the PI does not boot properly. I am using Teamviewer to remote to PI and it says the pI isactive but I just cannot logon. I had the same issue with another PI running raspian and that was an easy fix but I am at a loss as to what to try

Answer (score 0):

The command to reboot the system is `sudo reboot`.

You will be promoted to authenticate, and the system will reboot.

If you do not know how to run commands on your raspberry pi from another device you should research and ask about how to enable and configure SSH headless on a raspberry pi.

Comment: The above solution did work for me but how do I get th escreen back when I plug in a real monitor?